# javascript get digits after last non-numeric charachter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 input in form

```
<input type="text" name="full" />
<input type="text" name="FilterLeft" />
<input type="text" name="FilterRight" />
```

When user typing in $(#full), function must be devide value into left side after last non-numeric symbol, and right side after last non-numeric symbol.
For example, if user typed `'6s3f23234'`. 
I want to divide it into `$('#FilterLeft').val('6s3f')` and `$('#FilterRight').val('23234')`. How to do this? thanks.

Comment: Did you try using a regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = $('#full').val();
var matches = str.match(/(.*?)([\d]*$)/);

$('#Filterleft').val(matches[1] || '');
$('#FilterRight').val(matches[2] || '');
```

PS: You should pick one way to name your ids and stick to it. Either left should be capitalized in Filterleft, or Right should be made lowercase.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/ppaAM/1/)